# simple-navigation-bootstrap Gem, how to link to a Show Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I'm trying to realize a navigation menu for my app with the simple_navigation_bootstrap gem. 
This is my navigation.rb file, with all the paths in my app:

```
    if user_signed_in?

      primary.item :products, 'Products', products_path do |sub_nav|

        sub_nav.item :new_prod, 'New product', new_product_path
      end

      primary.item :orders, 'Open orders', orders_path do |sub_nav|
        sub_nav.item :new_order, 'new order', new_order_path
        sub_nav.item :old_orders, 'Closed orders', '/orders/order_history'
      end  

      primary.item :reservations, 'Reservations', reservations_path do |sub_nav|
        sub_nav.item :new_res, 'New reservation', new_reservation_path
      end

      primary.item :admin, 'Users', '/admin/user', if: proc { current_user.admin? }

      primary.item :wall, 'Wall', current_user.wall
    end
```

I use Devise for user authentication. I call the navigation menu in my views in this way:

```
<%= render_navigation(:expand_all => false) %>
```

I have an error that I cannot figure out: "undefined method 'split' for Wall.

With current_user.wall I point to the show action of the Wall for the signed_in User. Someone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Show the definition of the `wall` method and where it is used in association with the error

Comment: Wall is another object, where User has one Wall, and Wall belongs to User. I have the error "undefined method 'spli' for Wall" in the row of the view where I call the <%= render_navigation(:expand_all => false) %>

Comment: Nowhere in the code you posted are you attempting to call `split` on the `Wall` object. Update your code to show what you are trying to do. Also, read this: http://apidock.com/ruby/String/split

Answer (score 0):

I solved! passed the link to the show Action in the config/navigation.rb in the wrong way... I replaced with `primary.item :wall, 'muro', wall_path(current_user.wall)`